# Python Selenium Retweet Twitter

Tags: selenium

```
import selenium.webdriver 
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-username-field").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-password-field").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#page-container > div > div.signin-wrapper > form > div.clearfix > button").click()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/DisbeArex")
```

How do I retweet the most recent tweet using Selenium and Python? I know how to use it with the api, but when I try with Selenium i get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css selector should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".js-stream-item .ProfileTweet-action--retweet div").click()
```

Comment: return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (513.5, 9.25). Other element would receive the click: <div class="container"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

> a = driver.find_element_by_class('IconContainer')
>
> ....for i in a:
> ......a.click(0)

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

To retweet on the first tweet

> ret = 'section.css-1dbjc4n > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) >
> div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) >
> div:nth-child(1) > article:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) >
> div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) >
> div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) >
> svg:nth-child(2)'

Found element and click

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector(ret).click()

Confirm retweet

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.r-1j3t67a:nth-child(1)").click()